# iOS Core Image face detection: CIFaceFeature's 'hasMouthPosition' always true even when covering mouth

Tags: ios, swift, face-detection, core-image

I'm using CoreImage's CIDetector with CIDetectorTypeFace to detect faces and want to detect when the mouth is missing.

However, the detected CIFaceFeature's **hasMouthPosition** always seems to be true when my face is visible, even when I cover my mouth with an object such as my hand or a book.

Other properties such as **leftEyeClosed** change as expected, such as when I blink or cover an eye. I've tried using different CIDetectorAccuracy levels but it didn't help. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What makes you not think that it recognizes the hand or the book that you cover your mouse with as a mouth?

Comment: I guess that Core Image uses heuristics to _guess_ where your mouth would be based on the other facial features it detects. Did you check the actual position?